# How to add legend to the chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How can I add legend to the chart ([see fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/snec9kgf/2/))? I tried to define the legend as follows, but then the chart disappears (see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/snec9kgf/2/)).

```
var height = 900, width = 900;
var gridSize = Math.floor(width / 42);
var legendElementWidth = gridSize*2;

var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
              .data([0].concat(colorScaleDomain.quantiles()), function(d) { return d; });

legend.enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend");

legend.append("rect")
.attr("x", height)
.attr("y", function(d, i) { return legendElementWidth * (i-0.5); })
.attr("width", gridSize / 2 )
.attr("height", legendElementWidth)
.style("fill", function(d, i) { return colors[i]; });

legend.append("text")
.attr("class", "mono")
.text(function(d) { return "≥ " + Math.round(d) + "%"; })
.attr("x", (height) + gridSize)
.attr("y", function(d, i) { return legendElementWidth*i; } );

legend.exit().remove();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a list of the problems:

1. There is no `colorScaleDomain.quantiles()`. It should be `colorScale.quantiles()` instead.
2. The order of the elements is very important in an SVG, which has no z index. So, your legends...

   ```
   legend.enter().append("g")
       .attr("class", "legend");
   ```

...should come after the drawing code for the chart. But that step can even be ignored, because of the third problem:

3. Your legends are *outside* the SVG. I corrected that with:

   ```
   var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
       .attr("width", diameter + 200)//adding some space in the SVG
   ```

And some more magic numbers in the legends code. Change them accordingly (magic numbers are not a good practice in most situations).

Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hsq05oq9/

Comment: Thank you. What if I need absolute numbers to be displayed in the legend? Also, `colorScale` is already defined as quantile: `ar colorScale = d3.scale.quantile()
              .domain(colorScaleDomain)
              .range(colors);`. I slightly misunderstand why is it necessary to run again `colorScale.quantiles()` in `.data([0].concat(colorScale.quantiles()), function(d) { return d; });`?

Comment: `quantile()` is the scale. `quantiles()` returns the quantiles. They're different.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know this. Sorry. Anyway, I appreciate a lot if you could indicate how to get absolute numbers in the legend.

Comment: Just define your array.

Comment: Ok, I see. If I set `var colorScaleDomain = [300, 1000, 1800, 2500, 3000, 3500];`, then I get absolute numbers. Thanks. The problem, however, is that then everything is colored in the same color, though the scale seems to be correct. Please see this: https://jsfiddle.net/hsq05oq9/1/

Comment: No! Define *another* array, and in the text element use its index, like: `text((d,i) => anotherArray[i])`.

Comment: Ok, I tried this and it seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/hsq05oq9/6/   But after more precise analysis I see that the values assigned to colors in the legend do not correspond to the values of `size` and their colors in the drawing.

Comment: For instance, I checked `"name":"flare.analytics.cluster.AgglomerativeCluster","size":3938`. In the drawing it's marked with the "pink-red" color which corresponds to the legend `> 5000`.

Comment: Well, as this is *another* problem, please post another question. Forgive me, but I really don't like new questions in the comments. Besides that, if you post it as another question, not only you can better explain your needs, but more people are gonna read it.